# MQTT Java как подписаться на несколько тем?

Tags: java, eclipse, mqtt

Не понимаю как:

1. подписать темы
2. вывести темы

Вот что я пока написал:

```
public class ClientMQTT {

    public static final String HOST = "tcp://mqtt.by:1883";
    public static final String TopicKWH0 = "user/id/KWH0";
    public static final String TopicW1 = "user/id/W1";
    public static final String TopicW2 = "user/id/W2";
    private MqttClient client;
    private MqttConnectOptions options;
    private final String userName = "Login";
    private final String passWord = "Password";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    private void start() {
        try {
            client = new MqttClient(HOST, MqttClient.generateClientId(), new MemoryPersistence());
            options = new MqttConnectOptions();
            options.setCleanSession(false);
            options.setUserName(userName);
            options.setPassword(passWord.toCharArray());
            options.setKeepAliveInterval(61);
            options.setConnectionTimeout(601);
            client.setCallback(new PushCallBack());
            client.connect(options);

            int[] Qos  = {1};
            String[] topic = {TopicKWH0, TopicW1, TopicW2};
            client.subscribe(topic, Qos);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MqttException {
        ClientMQTT client = new ClientMQTT();
        client.start();
    }
}
```

```
public class PushCallBack implements MqttCallback {

    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
        System.out.println ("Соединение разорвано, вы можете переподключиться");
    }

    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
        System.out.println("deliveryComplete---------" + token.isComplete());
    }

    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
        if(topic.equals(ClientMQTT.TopicKWH0)){
            System.out.println("KWH0 - "+(new String(message.getPayload())));
        } else if (topic.equals(ClientMQTT.TopicW1)){
            System.out.println("W1 - "+(new String(message.getPayload())));
        } else if (topic.equals(ClientMQTT.TopicW2)){
            System.out.println("W2 - "+(new String(message.getPayload())));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В mqtt клиент указываем

```
public static final String Topic = "iotGoodways/id устройства/#";
client.subscribe(Topic);
```

В PushCallBack -> messageArrived прописываем условия

```
if(topic.equals("iotGoodways/id устройства/KWH0")){
            System.out.println("KWH0 - "+(new String(message.getPayload())));
        } else if (topic.equals("iotGoodways/id устройства/W1")){
            System.out.println("W1 - "+(new String(message.getPayload())));
        } else if (topic.equals("iotGoodways/id устройства/W2")){
            System.out.println("W2 - "+(new String(message.getPayload())));
        }
```